# Azure AD - Powershell -Federation Metadata Url is missing for federated user

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to Access my Azure AD using Powershell I am getting the below error

[Powershell Error screenshot as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lK94.png)

Any one please help me to understand why i am getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

**Error Message :**

> PS C:\Users\YYYYY> Connect-MsolService -Credential $password
>   Connect-MsolService : Authentication Error: Unable to complete
>   authentication request (potentially a proxy issue) At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-MsolService -Credential $password
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService

Comment: Well, I think it might be a proxy issue.

Comment: Instead of using an image link, try to copy and paste your code and the error message.

Comment: @mcNets, thank you. I have included error message.

Comment: @4c74356b41, thank you.. I will verify and keep you posted